# html2xlsx - How to select table with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using [html2xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2xlsx) plugin to export a html table to xlsx file. It works fine with the code included in the link above (shortened):

```
htmlTo(`
  <style type="text/css">
    table td {
      color: #666;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      border: 1px solid #eee;
    }
  </style>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>world</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td type="date">2013-01-12T12:34:56+08:00</td>
      <td type="datetime">2013-01-12T12:34:56+08:00</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
`, (err, file) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  file.saveAs()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.xlsx'))
    .on('finish', () => console.log('Done.'));
});
```

But, I want to use jQuery to select my table instead of writing html code.
I tried `htmlTo($(".table").html(), ...)` and also  `` htmlTo(`$(".table").html()`, ...) `` and even converted table html to string using `.toString()` but none works and exccel gives error.

Any suggestions?

Also, I'm using Electron.

## Update

The problem seems to be related to string formatting.
This one works:

```
tabul = '<tr><td>Hello</td></tr>'
htmlTo(`'<table>'` + tabul + `'</table>'`, ...)
```

But this doesn't:

```
tabledata = $(".table").html()
htmlTo(`'<table>'` + tabledata.toString() + `'</table>'`, ...) //excluding toString doesn't work either
```

## Update 2

There's another problem with images in the table. The plugin isn't able to transform image tags to data or maybe I don't know how.

Comment: Why not use the default datatable export feature? https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: @Carlos27 It adds a lot of functionality to my table. I just want export.

Comment: at least give it a try, believe me it works perfectly and it's fully compatible with the datatable plugin.

Comment: @Carlos27 What about Tableexport? It seems to be easy, but I don't how to require it in electron project.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".table").html()` just returns the contents of the table, but not the `<table>` tag itself. To get the HTML that includes the `<table>` tag, you can use the standard JavaScript `.outerHTML` property. Indexing a jQuery object returns the corresponding DOM element, so you can use

```
htmlTo($(".table")[0].outerHTML)
```

Comment: What you say seems to be the answer, but I think there is a problem with strings. This code works: ```htmlTo(`'<table>' + <tr><td>some data</td></tr> + '</table>'`,...)```. Notice the ` in the tags.

Comment: Backticks are part of template literal syntax, but you're not using literals, you want to get the HTML from the DOM. And I really don't understand why you've also put single quotes around `<table>`. You didn't need that in your original literal call to `htmlTo()`.